# c++ udp 10038 socket error on sendto()

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, sendto, recvfrom

I'm getting a 10038 socket error on a sendto() call. What could be causing this? I'm not getting any errors upon socket creation or binding. Here's how I set up my socket:

```
Client client;
client.client_socket = client.open_port(PEER_PORT2); //5001
client.prompt("Enter the router hostname: ",router);
client.sa_out = client.prepare_peer_connection(router, ROUTER_PORT2); //7001
```

**open_port**

```
SOCKET Client::open_port(int port)
{
    SOCKET sock; 
    SOCKADDR_IN sa;
    HOSTENT *hp; 
    char hostname[11]; 

    gethostname(hostname,11);

    if((hp=gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) 
        throw "Could not determine a host address from supplied name";

    sa.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sa.sin_port = htons(port);
    sa.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);

    if((sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))==INVALID_SOCKET) 
    throw "Generating a new local socket failed";

    if (bind(sock,(LPSOCKADDR)&sa,sizeof(sa)) == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    throw "Could not bind socket to supplied port";

    return sock;
}
```

**prepare_peer_connection**

```
SOCKADDR_IN Client::prepare_peer_connection(char* hostname, int port)
{
    SOCKADDR_IN sa;
    HOSTENT *hp;

    if((hp = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL) 
         throw "Could not determine a host address from supplied name";

    memcpy(&sa_out.sin_addr, hp->h_addr, hp->h_length);
    sa.sin_family = hp->h_addrtype;
    sa.sin_port = htons(port);

    return sa;
}
```

**The function with the sendTo() call causing the 10038**

```
int Client::send_packet(SOCKET sock, SOCKADDR_IN sa, char* buffer, int size, int pid)
{
    int ibytessent = 0;
    int packet_size = size + sizeof(int);
    int from = sizeof(sa); 
    char packet[132]; //128 + 4

    make_packet(packet, buffer, size, pid);

    if ((ibytessent = sendto(sock,packet,packet_size,0,(SOCKADDR*)&sa, from)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        throw "Send failed";
    }
    else
    {
        memset(buffer,0,size);
        return ibytessent - sizeof(int); 
    }
}
```

Comment: is value of sock after creation and before sendto - are same values?

Comment: Yes, when I cout the value of sock, it displays 372

Comment: Please show the code that is calling `client.send_packet()`, and also the code inside of `make_packet()`.  Maybe you have a buffer overflow that is overwriting `sock`.

Comment: Have you considered looking up what Winsock error 10038 means?

Comment: And why are you passing around a SOCKET as argument to your own member functions when it's already an instance member of the class?